# Angular Dynamic Pipe

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular-pipe

I am trying to build the dynamic pipe and though I have included the pipes in the app module provider, it is throwing the NullInjector error.

I would suggest to open the Console window inside the Developer options to see the error.

I have also attached the below link for the demo.

In a real scenario, the pipe value will be coming from the server so I am in need of a dynamic pipe.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lcidq5-q1a3hv?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `string` does not work as a valid token for the `inject` method.

I suggest creating an object that stores the types of your pipes:

```
import { Injector, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomPipe } from './custom.pipe';

const pipes = {
  fullform: CustomPipe,
};

@Pipe({
  name: 'dynamic',
})
export class DynamicPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  transform(value: any, pipeToken: any, pipeArgs: any[]): any {
    if (!pipeToken) {
      return value;
    } else {
      let pipe = this.injector.get<any>(pipes[pipeToken]);
      return pipe.transform(value, ...pipeArgs);
    }
  }
}
```

This way, you will have to add the pipes to this object for it to work, but you can pass the strings you get from your API and convert them to their respective  injector token.

Comment: Yes, this way it is working. Yeah before I looked at the solution when I tried to replace
let pipe = this.injector.get<any>(pipeToken); with let pipe = this.injector.get<any>(CustomPipe);, then it got worked. so yes string is not working as a valid token.

I can store the names of all pipes in one const

Answer (score 0):

You just to define a provider on the module

[image]

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent, TestComponent, DynamicPipe, CustomPipe],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TooltipsModule,
    DateInputsModule,
    ButtonsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    CustomPipe,
    DynamicPipe,
    { provide: 'fullform', useClass: CustomPipe },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

To inject the provider by string, you need to map the token to the pipe in the `app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [{ provide: 'fullform', useValue: CustomPipe }],
```

Then, in your dynamic pipe, you need to instantiate the pipe:

```
let Pipe = this.injector.get<any>(pipeToken);
let pipe = new Pipe();
return pipe.transform(value, ...pipeArgs);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lcidq5-w94gsj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic.pipe.ts